# vue flowbite error [vue/no-parsing-error] Parsing error: unexpected-character-in-unquoted-attribute-value.eslint-plugin-vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, eslint, flowbite

I'm giving it a try for flowbite-vue and I'm having this eslint unexpected character problem in VS-Code,

```
[vue/no-parsing-error]
Parsing error: unexpected-character-in-unquoted-attribute-value.eslint-plugin-vue

Unquoted attribute value cannot contain U+0022 ("), U+0027 ('), U+003C (<), U+003D (=), and U+0060 (`).vue(18)
```

the component Navbar has a dropdown and the `label={Avatar..` is showing this error

```html
<Dropdown
  arrowIcon={true}
  inline={true}
  label={Avatar alt="User settings" img="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/people/profile-picture-5.jpg" rounded={true}/>}
>
```

has anyone came through this and fixed it?
thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant this in Vue's realm

```html
<Dropdown
  arrow-icon
  inline
  label="Avatar alt='User settings'" 
  img="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/people/profile-picture-5.jpg" 
  rounded
/>
```

`rounded` assumes it's actually `:rounded="true"` but we can make it shorter that way.
Please also notice the semi-colon `:` which is a shorthand for `v-bind:`, needed when you need to interpolate what is inside of the double quotes (like an object).

Which is not the case in your situation: you use only strings.

---

More details available here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#attribute-bindings

Comment: yeap, this is excellent and working fine. My question is 'Avatar' component can be passed as an argument without tags? and the dropdown isn't showing , a hamburger menu is showing, image not rendering as well. (am I asking too much?)

Comment: @ArunPanneerselvam in Vue, you don't pass components like that. You can have various "slots" tho. Please take some time to read the documentation to fully understand how it works: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html